# How to use 2d array with mutable length as a function's parameters

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

Here is the function with magic numbers as lengths of the 2d arrays:

```
bool function(int char_block_a[7][2], int char_block_b[6][2])
{
    for (int i = 0; i = 7; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j = 6; j++)
        {
            if (char_block_a[i][0] == char_block_b[j][0] && char_block_a[i][1] == char_block_b[j][1])
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Here is the function with mutable length of 2d array that I wanted to implement (Just to show what I meant):

```
bool function(int char_block_a[a][2], int char_block_b[b][2])
{
    for (int i = 0; i = a; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j = b; j++)
        {
            if (char_block_a[i][0] == char_block_b[j][0] && char_block_a[i][1] == char_block_b[j][1])
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

How could I implement this? Thank you all!

Comment: You already have it. The most dominant dimension of an array (including array of arrays, etc), is effectively ignored when passed as you're doing, reducing to just a pointer. I.e. `int char_block_a[a][2]` is effectively `int char_block_a[][2]` .You just need to pass `a` and `b` as additional arguments and you're good.

Comment: `i = a` should probably be `i != a` etc.

Comment: Yeah somehow it got lost when I pasted down on here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 2D array arguments can be passed with unspecified numbers of rows and pass the respective numbers of active rows separately. Make sure the loops use the correct tests too:

```
/* check if 2D arrays have a row with identical values */
bool function(int char_block_a[][2], size_t a, int char_block_b[][2], size_t b) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < a; i++) {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < b; j++) {
            if (char_block_a[i][0] == char_block_b[j][0]
            &&  char_block_a[i][1] == char_block_b[j][1]) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
bool function(int char_block_a[7][2], int char_block_b[6][2])
                              ^^^                     ^^^
                                 The first dimension is ignored
```

You just have to *pass* **first** dimensions as *addition* arguments:

```
bool function(int char_block_a[][2], int char_block_b[][2], int a, int b)
                                                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~
```